# R data.table + ifelse with integer64, how to replace 0s and NAs?

Tags: r, data.table

I'm using `data.table` to read long numbers (e.g. 1,234,567,890,123) and I see that after doing an `ifelse` statement my column changes its structure.

This is what happens

```
class(imports$trade_value)
[1] "integer64"

# Then I replace 0s and NAs
imports$trade_value = ifelse(imports$trade_value == 0 | is.na(imports$trade_value), 
                             imports$trade_value_replacement, 
                             imports$trade_value)

class(imports$trade_value)
[1] "numeric"
```

I also have two `integer64` columns involved in the `ifelse` statement and it shows

```
class(imports_csv$trade_value_usd_replacement)
[1] "integer64"
```

How can I pass an argument to ifelse not to break the structure?

@Frank suggested a step and this is the solution: replace the `ifelse` statement by this

```
imports = imports[trade_value == 0 | is.na(trade_value), trade_value := trade_value_replacement]
```

Comment: You could continue using data.table and try `imports[v == 0 | is.na(v), v := r]`. Hard to know precisely why it breaks without a reproducible example or at least the class of the replacement vec.

Comment: thanks ! editing now

Comment: @Frank I kept myself using `data.table` and it worked :)

Comment: Cool, glad it worked! You could post how you got around it as an answer, I think. (There may be some time limit before you can "self-answer", though.)